# DokuWiki - Code Example Breaking

Tags: wiki, code-snippets, dokuwiki

When I put example code in the  tags it does not show as code but appears as normal text.

Can anyone shed some light on what is happening and how it can be corrected.

Screen Grab of code:
[image]

Output of what I get:
[image]

Comment: Do you close the block with `</code>` tag? It is not visible in the screenshot. It should work anyway, even better as `<code php>` I suppose, but check it out.

Comment: Also is it dokuwiki actually? Maybe some uncommon skin, but looks suspicious...